# Sockets vs Standard Streams for local client-server communication

Tags: python, sockets, air, stdout, stdin

I have an app that consists of a local "server" and a GUI client. The server is written in Python, while the GUI is meant to be changable, and is written in Flex 4. The client queries the local server for information and displays it accordingly. Both applications are meant to be run on the same computer, and will only communicate locally. At the moment, the client and the Python server communicates via a basic socket, the client writes a request to the socket, and the socket returns some data.

However, since I'm writing a desktop app, I thought it might be easier to maintain and to polish a system that uses standard streams instead of a socket. The server would listen for `raw_input()` continuously, and output according to anything written to stdin, and the client, in this case, would use AIR's `NativeProcess` class to read and write to stdout and stdin, rather than using sockets.

The client and server are separate processes, but are meant to be started at more or less the same time. I don't really have need for complex networking, just local cross-language communication.

What are the pros and cons of each approach? What would I gain or lose from using sockets, vs what I would gain or lose from using standard streams to communicate? Which one is more efficient? Which one is easier to maintain?

Answer (score 14):

On UNIX-like platforms, using stdin/stdout is a socket, so there's no difference. That is, if you launch a process with its stdout redirected, that'll typically be done with socketpair, so making your own UNIX-domain socket to communicate is unnecessary. The Python classes for handling stdin/stdout won't give you access to the full flexibility of the underlying socket though, so you'll have to set it up yourself I think if you want to do a half-close, for example (Python can't offer that cross-platform because the Windows sys::stdin can't be a socket, for example, nor is it always on UNIX.)

The nice thing about a local TCP connection is that it's cross-platform, and gives predictable semantics everywhere. If you want to be able to close your output and still read from the input, for example, it's much simpler to do this sort of thing with sockets which are the same everywhere. Even without that, for simplicity's sake, using a TCP socket is always a reasonable way to work around the wacky Windows mess of named pipes, although Python shields you from that reasonably well.